# Storing and representing nested vectors in QGIS

Tags: qgis

In a situation where you have geometry that sits physically within other geometry what is the right way to store and then represent this in QGIS?

Examples of this might include:

- Cables running inside of ducts
- Lanes running along roads
- Fibre running inside of cables

And I guess n-level depth of this too, eg fibre inside of cable inside of duct.

I have found that you can create joins to help with the view side for labeling. I have also found you can do field lookups on the data entry form to aid with accurate/useful data entry.

My concern is that you would end up with lots and lots of lines all overlaid on top of each other all holding the same geometry data when really you're trying to represent non-geometry objects that sit "underneath" geometry objects.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Understood, will expand

Comment: Storing in pretty clear: better to store them all. But what kind of representation in QGIS are you trying to achieve (what is the purpose of this representation)? A 2D Map (with offset) or 2.5D Map (with extrusion)?

Comment: It's to be able to document and interrogate for planning. In our particular use case I want to be able to document manholes and ducts, ducts and cables, cables and fibres, and how it all connects together.

Answer (score 0):

One polyline in the geographic map view then everything inside (eg ducts, cables & fibers) represented by using hierarchical data tree tables that have the ability to perform & represent the connectivity.

[This person explains it well.](https://youtu.be/ziULPFlmCO8)